# Azure SQL Database - Execution Timeout Expired error on several jobs

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database

In SQL Server Management Studio, I discovered an issue while attempting to disable a trigger on one of our tables in our Azure SQL Database, which is set at one of the highest-available performance tiers (Business Critical Gen 5). I used right-click disable to accomplish this.  I receive the following error after the timeout period expires:

```
Execution Timeout Expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding. (.Net SqlClient Data Provider)

        ------------------------------
        For help, click: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft%20SQL%20Server&ProdVer=12.00.0700&EvtSrc=MSSQLServer&EvtID=-2&LinkId=20476

        ------------------------------
        Server Name: searchfoundry.database.windows.net
        Error Number: -2
        Severity: 11
        State: 0


        ------------------------------
        Program Location:

           at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common.ConnectionManager.ExecuteTSql(ExecuteTSqlAction action, Object execObject, DataSet fillDataSet, Boolean catchException)
           at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common.ServerConnection.ExecuteNonQuery(String sqlCommand, ExecutionTypes executionType, Boolean retry)
The wait operation timed out
```

The help link goes to a 404 - no surprise there.

**EDIT #1:**
@DanGuzman kindly assisted me in suggesting I run the disable trigger as T-SQL. This worked.  However, in between the time I originally posted, and the time he gave his suggestion, I discovered that this timeout error is occurring within other areas of our infrastructure/services which use this database.

I have run a query to check for blocking sessions on this database.  There are none listed.  I have also increased the timeout period from 30 seconds to 5 minutes.  Items are still timing out.

I am looking for guidance on what other queries I can run to look under the hood of this database to determine what is causing these timeouts to occur.

I'd be happy to just restart the SQL Server to resolve this, but as many of us know, there is no restarting Azure SQL Servers, unfortunately.

Comment: Try using T-SQL from an SSMS query Window instead of Object Explorer: `DISABLE TRIGGER your_trigger ON dbo.your_table;`

Comment: Dan, that worked!  Thanks so much.  I still need to understand what is causing the timeouts (as mentioned in the post, I'm getting the timeout error now in other places, and I've increased the timeout parameter).  I think I'm going to edit this thread to be more general.  Thank you for getting me over this hump though!

Comment: Are using the latest SSMS version? This could be an issue with some SSMS OE actions rather than the database.

Comment: @DanGuzman I have updated my post to reflect that this error seems to be more widespread.  I have the trigger disabled now though, so thanks for that.

Comment: @DanGuzman I am on SSMS 17.6, and, I'm not sure if this other info has any meaning to you:

Comment: `Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio      14.0.17230.0
Microsoft Analysis Services Client Tools      14.0.1016.244
Microsoft Data Access Components (MDAC)      10.0.17134.1
Microsoft MSXML      3.0 5.0 6.0 
Microsoft Internet Explorer      9.11.17134.0
Microsoft .NET Framework      4.0.30319.42000
Operating System      6.3.17134`

Comment: @DanGuzman I think we can rule out SSMS because I am seeing the timeout errors in our Azure Storage Queues as well.

Comment: The current SSMS version as of this writing is 17.8.1. It's generally a good idea to use the latest with Azure. That might help with the drop trigger issue you had but of course not with timeouts unrelated to Azure SQL Database.

Comment: Dan, ah ok, I was not aware of a later version.  I will update right away.  Thank you again.

Answer (score 1):

Increasing the DTUs works for me.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had fixed similar timeout issues by increasing the DTU quota of the DB